# javascript unable to read array key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a 3 dimensional array which is pulled from a database with php, it is then parsed with json_encode. The array pulls information from different tables. Now if the column is empty it doesnt insert anything and moves onto the next key. The problem is whenever i try to check if the key is empty, javascript crashes. I have tried key.length, key === undefined and even tried to alert the key to see what was in it but javascript crashed.

PHP

```
    $Cats = array('bags', 'balls', 'clubs', 'putts', 'tees', 'gloves', 'promos');
    $Id = array('ID', 'Image_Path');
    include 'add.php';
    $filesFound = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
        for($s = 0; $s < 2; $s++){
            $query = "SELECT " . $Id[$s] . " FROM " . $Cats[$i];
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result)
            {
                echo "Database query Failed, contact Support" . $result; // -----ERROR MESSAGE
            }
            $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($result)
            {
                // Create while oop to loop table contents into array.
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $filesFound[$i][$s][] =  $row[$Id[$s]];
                }
            }else echo "query failed"; // -------------------------------ERROR MESSAGE
        }
    }
```

JavaScript

```
    var checkSelected = false;
    function submitCheck(ys){
        if(ys == ""){
            checkSelected = false;
        }else{
            checkSelected = true;
        }
    }
    function check(){
        if(checkSelected){
            document.getElementById("AddForm").submit();
        }
    }
    function selected(user) {
        //reset the div's.
        var x = document.getElementById('addDIV');
        x.innerHTML = "";
        //determine which one the user selected.
        switch (user) {
            case "Bags":
                a = 0;
                break;
            case "Tees":
                a = 4;
                break;
            case "Clubs":
                a = 2;
                break;
            case "Putts":
                a = 3;
                break;
            case "Balls":
                a = 1;
                break;
            case "Gloves":
                a = 5;
                break;
            case "Promos":
                a = 6;
                break;
            case "":
                return;
                break;
            default:
                return;
                break;
        }
        //variables for switch statement
        var Cats = new Array('bags', 'balls', 'clubs', 'putts', 'tees', 'gloves', 'promos');
        var div = "<div class='addedDiv'> ";
        var closingDiv = " </div>";
        var b = 0;
        var c = cat[a][0].length - 1;
        if (cat[a][0][0] == undefined) {
            x.innerHTML += div + "<p style='color: red;'>There are no images for this category</p>" + closingDiv;
        }else{
            for (i = 0; i < cat[a][0].length; i++) {
                var img = "<div class='staticDiv'><img src='../Images/" + cat[a][1][i] + "' width='300' height='200' /><form name='DelForm' method='POST' action='?'><input type='hidden' name='Lan' value='" + cat[a][0][i] + "'><input type='hidden' name='Image_Path' value='" + cat[a][1][i] + "'><input type='hidden' name='Cat' value='" + Cats[a] + "'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='SButt' value='Delete' /></form></div>";
                //if the loop is going to end before the end tag, force the end tag in.
                if (c == b) {
                    b = 2;
                }
                //Determine whether it needs to open or close a div
                switch (b) {
                    case 0:
                        x.innerHTML += div + img;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        x.innerHTML += img;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        x.innerHTML += img + closingDiv;
                        break;
                }
                //reset counter
                if (b == 2) {
                    b = 0;
                } else b++;

            }
        }                  
    }
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">var cat = <?php echo json_encode($filesFound); ?>;</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean `crashes`? what error shows up?

Comment: No error, the script doesn't run at all when i pass this key, all the rest do but this one refuses. I think it is because the array key never existed. Say array[0] had nothing to put in it, so it moves on to array[1], and array[0] is never created????

Comment: BTW -- You really do want to learn to use [Prepared Statements](http://us1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) instead of writing your own SQL.

Comment: The statement changes thats why it is written like that

Comment: You are missing quotes at the `var cat` declaration and could you post a `console.log` of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it one step at a time.
First check that cat[a] exists, then cat[a][0], and finally cat[a][0][0].
A short syntax to do so could be:

```
if (cat[a] && cat[a][0] && cat[a][0][0] !== undefined) { //Okey dokey }
else { //Oops }
```

Comment: It refuses to run it. It runs perfect but when i mention that empty key it gets angry

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot read the key because it simply does not exist. So you need to create a NULL key when inserting at the PHP, so that javascript can check.
PHP:

```
            //Check if there is any rows if not set to NULL
            if ($row_count)
            {
                // Create while oop to loop table contents into array.
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $filesFound[$i][$s][] =  $row[$Id[$s]];
                }
            }else $filesFound[$i][$s][] = NULL;
```